# FCM V1 API - How to receive notification on browser?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I migrated from legacy FCM to **v1 api**, by sending message with:
`https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' . $project_id . '/messages:send`
and params like this:

```
$headers = [
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->getGoogleAccessToken(),
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];
        $data = [
            'message' => [
                'notification' => [
                    'title' => $title,
                    'body' => $body,
                ],
                'data' => [
                    'custom' => 'test'
                ],
                'topic' => 'new-topic',
            ],
        ];
```

It sent success. But on the browsers nothing show (notification)

My question:

Could i send message without `topic` param?

How can I subscribeToTopic on my browser?

P/s: I got notificatoin on mobile if I use: `FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('new-topic');`

Comment: I can send with a ```token``` replace for ```topic```. The ```token``` get from ```getToken``` function via ```import { getMessaging, onMessage, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";```

Comment: There is not subscribeToTopic on browser. We should send message with token or send topic.